# Comparing the Suite and Value of Two Random Cards in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a program that will select two random cards from a deck (our instructor is having us use a dictionary to symbolize the deck) to see if they share the same suite (hearts, spades, etc.) or the same value (Aces, 2-10, J, Q, K). Keep in mind we haven't been taught Object-Oriented Programming yet so my knowledge on those concepts is limited. This is the code I have so far but unfortunately do not know where to go from here. How should I continue from here? Keep in mind I am using PYTHON.

```
import random 

def deck():
i = 0
suite = ['\u0003','\u0004','\u0005','\u0006']
nu = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
deck = []
total_count = []
for c in suite:
    for j in range(len(nu)):
        i += 1
        card = nu[j] + c
        deck.append(card)
        total_count.append(i)
deck_dictionary = dict(zip(deck, total_count))
print(deck, '\n\n')
print(deck_dictionary)
card1= random.choice(list(deck_dictionary.values())) 
card2 = random.choice(list(deck_dictionary.values()))
```

Comment: Please format your code to be the same as you're running it. The code you shared is indented in a way that will not run. You indicated the instructor suggested you implement the deck as a dictionary, but what exactly is the purpose of assigning the card number to each element (using `total_count`)?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the suits as:

```
    suite = ['\u0003','\u0004','\u0005','\u0006']
```

But were probably after something like:

```
    suit = ['\u2665', '\u2666', '\u2663', '\u2660']
```

I assume all the code after the `def` is the body of your function, and you call it from somewhere. However, if the function is really just the main program, there's not that much point in calling it as a function (unless it was something reusable, but it's clearly just the main program).

Having a function that generates a new deck might make sense though. However your code introduces a lot of extra variables and loops that aren't really doing all that much. It's unclear why you want to create a dictionary that maps each card to an initial position or unique number, but if that's what you need, something like this is enough:

```
def deck():
    suit = ['\u2665', '\u2666', '\u2663', '\u2660']
    value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    return {c: i for i, c in enumerate(f'{v}{s}' for s in suit for v in value)}
```

Or, if you want to stay closer to your code:

```
def deck():
    suit = ['\u2665', '\u2666', '\u2663', '\u2660']
    value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    i = 0
    result = {}
    for c in suit:
        for v in value:
            i += 1
            result[f'{v}{c}'] = i
    return result
```

The rest of your program doesn't really use the fact that you defined a dictionary like that and can't really take advantage of it, but you can still fairly easily get the list of cards, pick 2 at random, compare the suits and values and decide if they are the same:

```
deck_dictionary = deck()
print(deck_dictionary)

deck_list = list(deck_dictionary.keys())
card1 = random.choice(deck_list)
card2 = random.choice(deck_list)

print(f'picked {card1} and {card2}')
print('same suit' if card1[1] == card2[1] else 'not the same suit')
print('same value' if card1[0] == card2[0] else 'not the same value')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The reason I created a function is because our instructor is requiring us to do so. Also, I created the Deck and Total_count lists because I wasn't aware that there was an easier method of creating the dictionary, so I figured that I would use the deck as the keys and the total count as the values.

Comment: The last task I am required to complete is to remove the cards after each analysis. The code would finish once there is an empty deck of cards. I'm not sure as to how to remove these values out of the dictionary (converted to lists later in the program). What do you recommend?

Comment: It was probably the intention of the instructor for you to create a function for some specific reason - i.e. to return something for reuse, or to isolate the code because other parts of the program would be reusable. Similarly, you shouldn't create a dictionary for the purpose of creating a dictionary, but because there's reasons to pick a dictionary over a list - if you just use it as a list, picking the dictionary is the wrong choice. Removing a value from a dictionary can be achieved with `del()`, i.e. `del(d['key'])` removes the item with key `key` from dictionary `d`.